# CounterTester.java The Output is Correct but it is not decreasing correctly

Tags: java

Alright, I believe I have this program CounterTester.java down but in my output the program is increasing the way I want it to but it is not decreasing the way I want it to.

Any suggestions thank you.

```
/**
 * This program is used to test the Counter class.  It constructs the a counter 
 * using both constructors provided by the Counter class.
 *
 */
public class CounterTester
{
    static int myCount;

    public CounterTester() {
        int init = 1;
        myCount = init;
    }

    public CounterTester(int i) {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        CounterTester counter = new CounterTester();  //create a new counter with a step value of 1

        counter.increase(myCount); //add 1
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 1 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.increase(myCount++); //add 1
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 2 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease(); //subtract 1
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 1 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());


        counter = new CounterTester(10); //create a new counter with a step value of 10
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 0 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.increase(myCount++); //add 10
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 10 ----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease(); //subtract 10
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 0 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease(); //subtract 10
        System.out.println("Expected Count: -10 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

    }

    private String getCount() {
        return ""+myCount;
    }

    private void decrease() {
        myCount--;

    }

    private void increase(int i) {
        myCount++;

    }

    public void reset() {

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Look at your constructor - `public CounterTester(int i)` What should you do with this value `i`?

Comment: Your assignment is to fill in the blanks where it says `// TODO`. (You will also need a field to keep track of the count). `return null` is temporary and has to be replaces by something as well since that will just print `NULL`.

Comment: zapl - Should I use a calculation in the // TODO area?  I am kind of clueless.  I am definitely a beginner.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it with the increasing but I don't think I have the decrease down.  It is adding the numbers but not subtracting the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit as if you are expecting your code to behave the way you want simply because of the method names.  That won't work; you have to implement some logic into your code that actually stores and manipulates values.  Here's one way to do it:

Store the number of counts in a variable.

```
private int count;
```

Instantiate the variable with your constructor.

```
public CounterTester(int i) {
    this.count = i;
}
```

Add some basic logic to the following methods to manipulate or retrieve the variable:

```
private String getCount() {
    // return the count variable
    return Integer.toString(this.count);
}

private void decrease() {
    // decrease the count by 1
    this.count--;

}

private void increase() {
    // increase the count by 1
    this.count++;

}

public void reset() {
    // reset the count to 1
    this.count = 1;

}
```

Also, just a note on your `getCount()` method.  Right now, you've declared it to return a value of type `String`, which makes it necessary to convert the count value to a String with `Integer.toString(this.count).`  It would be simpler to just make the `getCount()` method return an int.  So instead of this:

```
private String getCount() {
    // return the count variable
    return Integer.toString(this.count);
}
```

You should do this:

```
private int getCount() {
    // return the count variable
    return this.count;
}
```

Finally, these methods seem like the kind you might want to call in another class, so I'd recommend making all these methods `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: Seems like an homework assignment. Not sure if it's a good idea to give the whole solution. You could give some hints instead. And your `getCount()` method won't compile.

Comment: @ZouZou Right.  Didn't notice the return at first.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Also I think in general you're right, but Diana Magers is very new at this I think showing her how to retrieve and manipulate data in Java may be the best way to help.

Answer (score 0):

because you return null from `getCount()` method

```
private String getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

none of those methods/constructor has actual implementation  so it won't behave as expected

Answer (score 0):

Adding this new answer to reflect the updated question.

As your code now stands, there are several problems.

**The first problem** is that your variable, `myCount`, is static.  It shouldn't be.  Now, I suspect the reason you made it static is because you were trying to access it in the static main method, which caused errors, and then your IDE (I'm guessing it's eclipse) suggested to you to make the variable static to fix the error.

You need to understand the difference between static and non-static variables and methods.

If a variable is static, that means it belongs to the class itself, and can be accessed from the class name.  If a variable is non-static, then it belongs to an instance of that class and has to be accessed from an instance of the class.  So, instead of making my `myCount` static, remove the static modifier and access `myCount` off of an instance of your class:

```
// create a new counter (an instance of CounterTester) with a step value of 1
CounterTester counter = new CounterTester();

// use counter.myCount instead of just myCount
counter.increase(counter.myCount);
```

When you made `myCount` static, the result was that all your new CounterTesters shared the same count, so when you made a `new CounterTester(10)` its count was still 3.

**The second problem** is that it seems you want to specify the amount you want to increase or decrease your steps, but your methods aren't implemented correctly.  The increase method is currently:

```
private void increase(int i) {
    // increment by 1
    myCount++;
}
```

But is should be:

```
private void increase(int i) {
    // increment by i
    myCount += i;
}
```

Be sure to do the same thing for your decrease method.

**The third problem** is that your constructor without args doesn't assign a value to `myCount`, but you are assuming that it was assigned a value of 1.  If that's what you want, then in your constructor without args just go `myCount = 1;`.

**The fourth problem** is that you are incrementing `myCount` by 1 when you pass it in, which throws your answer off by 1.  So don't do this:

```
counter.increase(counter.myCount++);
```

Just do this:

```
counter.increase(counter.myCount);
```

**The fifth problem** is that you are making a new Counter(10), and then expecting its count to be 0.  Perhaps I don't understand your intent correctly?  The count should be 10, not 0, so I think your expectation should change here.

**The sixth problem** is that it seems you are expecting a no-args decrease method to somehow decrease the count by the same amount it was last increased at.  If you want your code to behave this way, you'll have to create another variable to store the last increase amount.

**The seventh problem** is that, you are passing in `myCount` as an argument to increase `myCount`.  When you do this multiple times, you are not incrementing the value of myCount -- you are in fact increasing it exponentially by doubling it.  But the comment on your code when you do it a second time implies that you are only trying to increase it by 1.  Maybe you should just pass in an int literal (`counter.increase(1)`) instead of the variable itself (`counter.increase(counter.myCount)`).